# Can't change permissions on new files

Tags: terminal, finder, permission

I have a laptop running 10.12.5. I copied a folder of photos from a DVD to the Desktop. Here's what happens next:

1. I can open the folder on the desktop and see the files listed.
2. I can see the thumbnail images in the preview pane above the file listing.
3. However, I *cannot* open any of the photos: I get a message saying I don't have permission to view it and inviting me to change permissions by going to File > Get Info.
4. When I do that, I see that I'm listed as having RW permission already.

## And here's where it gets weird...

I figured I'd try `chmod`, so I opened Terminal.

`cd ~/Desktop/new_folder` returns the message: `No such file or directory`.

But if I do `ls ~/Desktop`, the folder is listed. `ls -l` indicates that the file permissions are `drwxr-xr-x`.

So, to recap:

1. The Finder can show thumbnails, but not actually open the images.
2. Get Info says I have RW permissions, but apparently I don't.
3. `ls` can see the directory with the photos in it, but `cd` doesn't think it exists.

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

## Oh, and one more thing...

Other photos imported from the same DVD do not have the same problem. So far it's just the one folder.

Comment: Does it also happen if you delete the photos and copy them over again? What happens if you type cd and drag the folder into the terminal window? Same error? What if you copy the pictures out of the folder into another location? Did you try from another user account? How about putting it on an external drive and trying to open it on another Mac/PC? What happens if you try to mail these pictures or upload them via Safari or some other app, and then trying to download them again? Can you view the files using an external app (I assume you used Preview)? Can you Quick Look them properly?

Comment: Just wondering if there's anything you could be missing

Comment: I've had this weirdness before with finder but never through a terminal. Could you try disk utility repair? Sounds like some record is missing and the file system isn't sure where everything is